# Unable to save video using OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, video-processing

I am new to Computer Vision, I started my journey of Image Processing by using Pillow and Skimage Library than I tried with opencv but when I am using opencv for video processing I am unable to save my video captured by system camera.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
video_write = cv2.VideoWriter('saved_out.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))
while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    video_write.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
video_write.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is the resolution of your webcam image?

Comment: Here is the details of my web Camera

Webcam Name: HP HD Camera
Quality Rating: 476
Frame rate: 17 FPS
Stream Type: video
Image Mode: rgb
Webcam MegaPixels: 0.92 MP
Webcam Resolution: 1280×720
Video Standard: HD
Aspect Ratio: 1.78
PNG File Size: 1.35 MB
JPEG File Size: 724.01 kB
Bitrate: 12.06 MB/s
Number of Colors: 209890

Comment: I have tried with the actual resolution by using

'h, w = frame.shape[:2]'

Comment: Trying with the actual resolution didn't help?

Comment: yes I tried with actual resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried mp4v instead of xvid? The following works for me (windows):

```
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('out.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 20, shape)
```

If this doesn't work you can also try:

1. Don't hard code the video dimensions, use frame.shape instead to make sure the dimension match. If they don't the writer cannot write the frame.

   ret, frame = video.read()
   height, width = frame.shape[:2]
   shape = (width, height)
   video_write = cv2.VideoWriter('saved_out.avi', fourcc, 20.0, shape)

IMPORTANT: if you are creating a frame from a np array, remember that width and height are inverted. I lost 2 hours on a Saturday debugging this on my code.

```
newFrame = np.zeros((height, width), dtype='uint8')
```

2. The frame needs to be in BGR format (3 channels). If grayscale image is used, you must pass the flag False for color when instantiating your writer object, like so:

   writer = cv2.VideoWriter('out.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 20, shape, False)

Docs: VideoWriter(​filename, fourcc, fps, size, is_color​)